# Is it possible to do an for "for" in an PSObject?

Tags: powershell

I want a output that depends on my layers, it can range from 1 to 50, so that my code is a bit more flexible.

Normally I could do that so:

```
$outputArray += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
  'Layer 1' = ''
  'Layer 2' = ''
  'Layer 3' = ''
  'Layer 4' = ''
   ...
}
```

But what if I have like 50 layers?
Is it possible to do a "for" or something similiar to create the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to solve this with something like this

```
$obj = New-Object PSObject
1..50 | foreach { $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Layer $_" -Value '' }
```

Alternatively like this (basically the same thing but a tad more compact code).

```
$obj = New-Object PSObject
1..50 | foreach { $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{ "Layer $_" = '' }}
```

As for adding values, it could be done in a few different ways but it all depends on what is known and at what time etc. You could for instance do something like this right away;

```
$obj = New-Object PSObject
$values = 50..1
1..50 | foreach { $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{ "Layer $_" = $values[$_ -1] }}
```

Or add values separately with `$obj.'Layer 1' = "Autumn"`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to notjustme's answer, I would not recommend adding each property individually, but collecting them in a hashtable first, and using that for `-Property`, because the performance should be better.

```
$properties = @{}
# foreach-loop is faster than ForEach-Object cmdlet
foreach($i in 0..50) { $properties["Layer $i"] = "something"}
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
```

Comment: Nice; note that a shorter (and slightly more efficient) way to convert the hashtable is to simply cast it to `[pscustomobject]`: `$obj = [pscustomobject] $properties`